# How to add delay in Reactor Netty HttpSever response

Tags: reactor-netty

I have created a Reactor Netty HTTPSever which works fine, I wanted to add an delay for each response i.e if I send a request I should get the response after say 10 sec, I need this delay to test something. Below is the code used to create the server

```
DisposableServer server = HttpServer.create().port(port).protocol(HttpProtocol.H2C).metrics(true, s -> s)
                    .wiretap(false).handle((request, response) -> response.status(httpResponseStatus).send()).bindNow();
    
    server.onDispose().block();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`send()` method returns `Mono`, so you can invoke the `delay*` operators that `Mono` provides. The example above can be changed like this (this example below delays headers and sends an empty response body):

```
DisposableServer server = 
            HttpServer.create()
                      .port(port)
                      .protocol(HttpProtocol.H2C)
                      .metrics(true, s -> s)
                      .wiretap(false)
                      .handle((request, response) ->
                          response.status(httpResponseStatus)
                                  .send()
                                  .delaySubscription(Duration.ofSeconds(10)))
                      .bindNow();
            
server.onDispose().block();
```

**Update:**
In case the I/O handler needs first to delay and then to send some non empty response, the example can be change to the one below:

```
DisposableServer server = 
            HttpServer.create()
                      .port(port)
                      .protocol(HttpProtocol.H2C)
                      .metrics(true, s -> s)
                      .wiretap(false)
                      .handle((request, response) ->
                          Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                              .flatMap(l -> {
                                  // Set status code if needed
                                  response.status(httpResponseStatus);
                                  return response.sendString(Mono.just(String.valueOf(responseCode)).then();
                              }))
                      .bindNow();
                
server.onDispose().block();
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but it did not worked

Comment: where as this code works but I am not bale to send the HTTP Status with this code .HTTP 200 status is sent always, how do i send other HTTP status like 500, 403 etc with this code. Any help would be highly appreciated --------------------->  

server = HttpServer.create().port(port).protocol(HttpProtocol.H2C).metrics(true, s -> s)
     .wiretap(false).handle((request, response) ->  response.sendString(Mono.just(String.valueOf(responseCode)).
       delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(delay)))).bindNow();

Comment: Thanks for the solution , it worked for me , would like to know what is the diff between first and the second solution

Comment: with the second snippet you can change the response code after the delay