# WebServerFactoryCustomizer is not hit in a Springboot Webflux app

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

Following [Configure the Web Server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.webserver.configure) , I add a `NettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer`

```
@Configuration
public class NettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<NettyReactiveWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(NettyReactiveWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.addServerCustomizers(httpServer -> {
            return httpServer
                .wiretap(true)
                .metrics(true, s->s)
                .doOnConnection(conn -> {
                    conn.addHandlerFirst(new ReadTimeoutHandler(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                });
        });
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

1. When I run the app, the `customize`  function is not hit. Where do I miss?
   My purpose is to enable the [Netty metrics](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_metrics_4), I can't find any documents about config the metrics in the `application.yml` file. so I add the `NettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer`.
2. The second parameter of `.metrics(true, s->s)` is a `uriTagValue`, Are there any example about how to pass in value? I just use `s->s` because I refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71235334/how-to-add-delay-in-reactor-netty-httpsever-response), but this maybe can't avoid [cardinality explosion](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/1075), Are there any function like `ServerWebExchange.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE)` simple give us the templated URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the workaround of the question 1: define a bean instead of implementing WebServerFactoryCustomizer

```
@Bean
    public ReactiveWebServerFactory reactiveWebServerFactory() {
        NettyReactiveWebServerFactory factory = new NettyReactiveWebServerFactory();
        factory.addServerCustomizers(builder -> builder
                .wiretap(true)
                .metrics(true,s->s)
                .accessLog(true)
                .doOnConnection(conn -> {
                    conn.addHandlerFirst(new ReadTimeoutHandler(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                }));

        return factory;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**About your question 2**  : *The second parameter of .metrics(true, s->s) is a uriTagValue, Are there any example about how to pass in value?*

```
private static final Pattern URI_TEMPLATE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("/test/.*");

@Bean
public ReactiveWebServerFactory reactiveWebServerFactory() {
    NettyReactiveWebServerFactory factory = new NettyReactiveWebServerFactory();
    factory.addServerCustomizers(builder -> builder
            .wiretap(true)
            .metrics(true,
              uriValue ->
            {
                Matcher matcher = URI_TEMPLATE_PATTERN .matcher(uriValue);
                if (matcher.matches()) {
                    return "/test/";
                }
                return "/";
            }               
            .accessLog(true)
            .doOnConnection(conn -> {
                conn.addHandlerFirst(new ReadTimeoutHandler(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
            }));

    return factory;
}
```